# Editar dados em modal preenchedo com dados do banco php

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um formulário que faz a edição dos dados do banco com base no id recebido.

```js
/*
função para atualizar os dados quando clicado em submit
*/

$('.editfoto').submit(function () {
        var form = $(this);
        var dados = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $("#btnEdit").prop("disabled", true);

        id = $(this).data("idedit");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'editafoto.php?id=' + id,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: dados,
            type: 'GET'
        }).done(function (data) {
            fetchUser();
            alert("Dados Atualizados com Sucesso");
            console.log("STATUS : ", data);
            $("#btnEdit").prop("disabled", false);
            $('#modalEdit').modal('hide');
            $('.editfoto')[0].reset();

        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            $("#btnEdit").prop("disabled", false);
        });
        return false;

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- chama o modal -->
 <a id="editfoto" data-idedit="<?php echo $row['idfoto']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar Foto</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="editfoto" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" id="idfoto" name="idfoto" value="<?php echo $ftvi->getIdfoto(); ?>" />
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                        <div class="col col-lg-3">
                            <label class="control-label" for="datavisita">Data Vísita</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-lg-6">    
                            <input type="text" name="dtvisita" id="dtvisita" required autocomplete="off" class="form-control  form-control-sm form-group small" value="<?php echo $ultil->formataData($ftvi->getIdfoto()); ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                        <div class="col col-lg-3">
                            <label class="control-label" for="idvisita">Visíta</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col col-md-6'>   
                            <input type="text" name="idvisita" id="idvisita" readonly class="form-control  form-control-sm form-group small" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                        <div class="col col-lg-3">
                            <label class="control-label" for="percentandamento">Porcentagem Andamento</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-md-6 slidecontainer">
                            <input type="range" name="percentandamento" id="percentandamento" required min="1" max="100" value="<?php echo $ftvi->getPercentandamento(); ?>" class="form-control-range slider" oninput="disp.value = percentandamento.value">
                            <output  id="disp"></output>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                        <div class="col col-lg-3">
                            <label class="control-label" for="caminhofoto">Foto</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>   
                            <input type="file" name="caminhofoto" id="caminhofoto" required class="form-control-file form-control-sm form-group small" accept="image/png,image/jpg" value="<?php echo $ftvi->getCaminhofoto(); ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                        <div class="col col-lg-3">
                            <label class="control-label" class="control-label" for="descricaofoto">Descrição Foto</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-md-auto'>                
                            <textarea name="descricaofoto" id="descricaofoto" cols="25" rows="3" class="form-control  form-control-sm form-group small" ><?php echo $ftvi->getDescricaofoto(); ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo passar as informações do PHP para o Modal.
para que ele carregue as informações para ser editada.

Encontrei um exemplo que usa data-atributos, porém se eu for colocar todos data-atributos no meu  link de chamada ele vai ficar enorme.
Já tem um tempo que tento resolver esse problema e nada.

Tenho a listagem e ao clicar no icon/link editar ele abra um modal como esse do adicina, só que com os dados carregados do banco.
Um print:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer puxar os dados da sua página PHP para a JS correto? Nessa situação a única situação 'correta' para se aplicar é realizar uma requisição via JS para a página em PHP. Não tem como o servidor enviar informações para o front sem uma requisição, a menos que você utilize WebSockets.

Answer (score 1):

Percebi um erro de sintaxe no seu código que pode não estar permitindo você encontrar o id correto do que quer editar:

```
url: 'editafoto.php=id' + id,
```

Onde deveria na verdade passar:

```
url: 'editafoto.php?id=' + id,
```

a "?" é para sinalizar que a partir deste ponto inicia-se a sua "Query String", e você diz que há um "parâmetro" chamado "id" cujo valor "=" é o conteúdo da variável "id".

Mas você também já tem um campo do tipo HIDDEN no formulário como o nome "idfoto" que vai passar esse valor, então, você realmente precisa montar essa query string na url da página que está chamando?

Tenha muito cuidado com relação à segurança, pois, qualquer usuário poderá alterar esse "ID" e submeter o formulário, alterando então os dados de outro registro, que pode não ser o adequado.

Vale também aí entender que se você está pretendendo carregar uma lista de fotos para abrir cada uma em um modal, dessa forma você terá que carregar todos os dados de todas as fotos da lista na tela para abrir uma por uma, ou seja, seu retorno html poderá ficar enorme. uma maneira mais econômica talves seria carregar a lista e ao clicar em uma foto, carregar os dados a serem editados por meio de ajax.

Talvez eu não tenha respondido sua questão, mas preferi relacionar aqui alguns alertas que poderão te dar alguma orientação de por onde seguir.

Comment: Exatamente isso que quero fazer.

"uma maneira mais econômica talves seria carregar a lista e ao clicar em uma foto, carregar os dados a serem editados por meio de ajax."

Eu tenho a listagem exibida na tela, ao clicar no botão editar só preciso que abra o modal com os dados carregados.
Vou postar um print do insert na pergunta.